# ValueError: Dotenv specified in config but not found at path

Tags: python, brownie

Hello there I'm currently following this [tutorial by Patrick Collins](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p36tXHX1JD8) however I'm stuck at deploy script.

```
PS C:\Users\aixax\Desktop\nft-from-scratch> brownie run scripts/advanced_collectible/deploy_advanced.py
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.17.1 - Python development framework for Ethereum

  File "C:\Users\aixax\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\eth_brownie-1.17.1-py3.10.egg\brownie\_cli\__main__.py", line 64, in main
    importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{cmd}").main()
  File "C:\Users\aixax\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\eth_brownie-1.17.1-py3.10.egg\brownie\_cli\run.py", line 41, in main
    active_project.load_config()
  File "C:\Users\aixax\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\eth_brownie-1.17.1-py3.10.egg\brownie\project\main.py", line 453, in load_config
    _load_project_config(self._path)
  File "C:\Users\aixax\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\eth_brownie-1.17.1-py3.10.egg\brownie\_config.py", line 199, in _load_project_config
    raise ValueError(f"Dotenv specified in config but not found at path: {env_path}")  
ValueError: Dotenv specified in config but not found at path: C:\Users\aixax\Desktop\nft-from-scratch\.env
```

I'll inlclude my python , brownie config and .env file for the reference. The private key is my own private key with 0x at the front.

deploy_advanced.py :

```py
from brownie import AdvancedCollectible, accounts, network, config

def main():
   dev = accounts.add(config['wallets']['from_key'])
   print(dev)
```

brownie-config.yaml:

```yaml
dependencies: 
- OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0
- smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.0.2
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
     - '@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0'
     - '@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.0.2'
dotenv: .env
wallets:
  from_key: ${PRIVATE_KEY}
  from_mnemonic: ${MNEMONIC}
```

file.env:

```
export PRIVATE_KEY={0x___________________________________________________________}
```

Comment: dependencies: 
- OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0
- smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.0.2
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
     - '@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0'
     - '@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.0.2'
dotenv: .env
wallets:
  from_key: ${PRIVATE_KEY}
  from_mnemonic: ${MNEMONIC}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i need it to give me an output which is my address

Answer (score 1):

Your `.env` file is located at the wrong place.

It's expecting it to be at `\Users\aixax\Desktop\nft-from-scratch\.env`

You'll either need to move the file there, or update in your `brownie-config.yaml` where it's located at the `dotenv` key.

Answer (score 0):

`.env` file should be at root of your project. i.e. Here your root directory is `\Users\aixax\Desktop\nft-from-scratch\`.

So your  `.env` file should be at `C:\Users\aixax\Desktop\nft-from-scratch\.env`